# NSTextView frame issue inside NSTableView

Tags: frame, nstableview, nstextview

I want to put a attributed string on a nstextview, and manually calculate the height of the textview and row

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row
```

inside

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
    {
        WBMessageTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"wbCell" owner:self];

        //do some calculation, and update textview's frame
        textView.frame = CGRectMake(57.0f, 36.0f-height, 380.0f, height);
    }
```

height is the calculated result for NSTextView.

everything is fine for the first time,
[image]

but if I scroll, the TextView starts move down,
[image]

it has been bugs me for a day, does anyone knows why? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out by myself.

the answer is I need to override `prepareForReuse`, and reset the cell's frame to the original size, so the calculation is good.